# Swift iOS solution for multiple/relational drop down pickers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I am new to programming iOS and I am not sure on how to implement multiple/relational drop down pickers into my design.

I have a search form in my app that works like a panel-menu. If you click on the search icon then the panel slides in with the search form.

But what is the best way to implement multiple/relational drop down pickers for my search form?

The pickers are relational. First you select a **state** then you must select a **city**. Once you selected a state in dropdown1 then dropdown2 should get populated depending on what you selected in dropdown1.

So is there any good solution for this when it comes to design?

I would like to show both pickers at all time. Kinda like a datepicker when year / month / day always is shown.

But if anyone has a good resource example on relational pickers please share.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'd encourage you to reconsider choosing a picker :)  Search bars and tableViews work so well together, Apple provided `UISearchController`.  It's much faster (and less annoying) to scroll through a tableView, especially since it offers a built-in index!

Comment: @PetahChristian thanks, I will use that for state/city. But when it comes to category/subcategory users often want to scroll through the list in order to see what there is to choose from. So I was thinking of linking two tableviews. First one you chose a category then you end up on tableview two and chose a subcategory and once you do that you end up back in the search form. But what do you call that type of relational table views? - so I can google some example on github. I want  tableview nr1 to be populated based on what you chose in tableview nr1. Thanks once more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this up with nested UITableViewControllers.

These types of projects are generally called Master/Detail.

The Master tableView would display the list of categories.

Once the user has selected a category, the specific category is passed to the detail View controller.  It queries all the subcategories for that category.

This can all by done in Storyboard, using Auto Layout, self-sizing cells, and a combination of show and unwind segues.

- A show segue pushes a (table) view controller onto the navigation controller stack.  In your case, the category controller would push a subcategory controller.  `prepareForSegue:sender:` is where the category controller would provide the category to the subcategory controller.
- An unwind segue returns from a view controller, popping it off the navigation stack. In your case, the subcategory controller would return (with the selected subcategory information) to the category controller, or a previous view controller.

It may sound like a lot to digest, but if you read up on recent (i.e. for iOS 8) walkthroughs which use these concepts, you'll have learned some acceptable practices for how information and control should flow within an app.

There's one more thing I didn't mention, called Core Data.  Core Data, and `NSFetchedResultsController` would be a great tool to learn and use for the app.  It's probably more complex than anything I previously mentioned, but once you get a handle on it, you will really appreciate it, and may end up using it in many apps!

Don't get too bogged down with how your app should look.  Focus on how the model and view controllers are written, and get a good understanding of the underlying frameworks.  That's more important right now, than any fancy transition/animation.

The design of any app will evolve as you use it.  You'll discover what works well, and what doesn't, so don't get too attached to any one way of organizing the data!

Hope that helps!  Enjoy programming for iOS, it's a great platform!

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your awesome response!! You mentioned a lot of fun techniques. I will def look into core data :) I will vote up soon as my rep gets higher.